# url encode & url escape & url rewrite, what's the differences?

Tags: url, url-rewriting, escaping, urlencode

It's kinda confusing to differenciate those three terms.
It'll be more understandable if you can explain with examples.

Answer (score 1):

Url encoding and Url escaping are one and the same..

URL Encoding is a process of transforming user input to a CGI form so it is fit for travel across the network; basically, stripping spaces and special characters present in the url, replacing them with escape characters.

URL rewriting changes the way you normally associate urls with resources. Normally, test.com/aboutus makes us think that it will take us to the about us page. But internally, Server may take user 1 to /aboutus/page1.html, user 2 to /aboutus/page2.html or any other resource. The Url exposed to the end user will be test.com/aboutus but the resource being rendered can be different. Note that Url Rewriting is performed by Server.

Comment: Are all implementation versions of url-encoding the same? (Since I notice that different versions of base64-encoding result int different characters)